# Visual Studio colors not loaded correctly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I use a custom color scheme in Visual Studio (black background, gray text, etc.). There a few settings that refuse to change, however. For example, when cursoring through the markup for an aspx page, the current tag defaults to black text, which doesn't work well on my black background. I've previously changed the appropriate setting to a "visible" color. In fact, to fix it, all I have to do is open the Options window, check and uncheck the Bold setting on Plain Text and hit OK, and now all my chosen settings are properly loaded. If I open a new session though, I have to go through these steps again. There are only a few settings where I notice this behavior (the Read-Only Region is another one), but it's annoying to have to do a dummy option change to get them to kick in. Has anyone seen this behavior before, and does anyone have a fix/workaround?

UPDATE: Found an interesting fix. I still don't know what the root cause is (probably some corruption as @sliderhouserules suggessts), but I've got a quicker way to fix it than using Tools | Options | Fonts and Colors. I simply exported my current color settings and created a macro to load them in:

```
Public Sub ImportColors()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "-import:""C:\Documents and Settings\gregf\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Settings\FontsAnColors_Exported-2008-12-05.vssettings""")
End Sub
```

I then mapped that macro to a button on my toolbar. Now I have a one-click fix whenever my colors go awry. Not ideal, but much less painful now.

Comment: i see the same problem with VS 2010. going to the fonts&colors options dialog and clicking 'OK' forces the editor to reload the correct colors. but it's quite annoying as I have to do this every time I start VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you may have some corruption in your VS install or something (IE you need to reinstall VS). This doesn't sound like a bug, and you'd be fishing in the dark trying to repair your registry or whatever config files are involved in setting and storing these options for VS.